# my tostring is display ={ my data} how do i remove it

Tags: java, tostring

when i try to vew the toString it viewing equal signs and brackets like this ={username age gender userid  } how can i make it not apear

asking it to display it `jtaUsers.setText("");
     jtaUsers.append ("\nUserID Username  Gender   Age\n" + db.toString());`

this is my toString

```
 public String toString()
{
    return"       "+ username +"     " + gender + "     " + age + " \n";
}
```

Comment: please ask your question clearly, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Tag the question with the language.

Comment: I am trying to view the data from the tostring, the data is been displayed but the problem is that there are characters been displayed as well for example this is displayed {121=       smith     male     34}

Comment: I suggest reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for advice on writing good questions.

Answer (score 0):

A method will return exactly what you tell it to return; nothing will make this method return braces and an equal sign. What's probably happening is that you're calling some *other* `toString()`, method, which is calling this one as part of its execution. That other `toString()` is what's providing the braces and equals sign.

Comment: I am trying to view the data from the tostring, the data is been displayed but the problem is that there are characters been displayed as well for example this is displayed {121=       smith     male     34}

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if the toString() method in your class is the one you are actually using in your driver class.

I'm guessing that the output you are seeing was from generated code. You might have a the wrong class imported. I would check your imports, as well.

Comment: It would be better to include all the relevant source in the question. That not only makes the question durable against pastie deletions, but it also means the question is useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: Yes you right thanks will bear in mind, even though I am banded from asking questions